# implement OOP delegation that does not violate Encapsulation

Tags: java, oop, uml, encapsulation, ooad

this is a simple scenario about gambling.
there is a gambler and dice.
gambler can roll the dice.then dice value will change

For the above scenario i created this Class diagram

[image]

as shown in above diagram
gambler can roll the dice, it's implement in `Gambler.roll()` method
when gambler roll the dice, dice value is changing, it's implement in `Dice.roll()` method

implement the above scenario using java code as shown below
please note this code as pseudo code,syntax can be wrong

```
class Gambler{
  private Dice dice;

  Gambler(Dice dice){
    this.dice = dice;
  }

  public void roll(){
    dice.roll();//delegation call
  }
}

/* --------------------------- */

import java.util.Random;
class Dice{
  private int faceValue;

  public int getFaceValue(){
    return faceValue;
  }


  public void roll(){
    //get random value between 1 ,6
    Random random = new Random();
    this.faceValue =  random.nextInt((6 - 1) + 1) + 1;
  }
}
```

I want to know
Is my implementation according to OOAD best practices and does not violate the encapsulation ?

specially when delegating rolling the dice from `Gambler` to `Dice` class
is it correct `Gambler` has `roll()` method ?

Comment: Your `Gambler` is delegating `roll` to a `Dice` correctly (although you still need a way to retrieve the value in `Gambler`). What I'm concerned about is why a `Dice` is stateful (i.e. Why it has a face value instead of returning what it rolled).

Comment: because faceValue attribute is something that describe the dice state,that state is belongs to dice class,that is why faceValue class variable is in dice class

Comment: Does the '2' represent the number of dies or the number of rolls?

Comment: @NicholasK number of dices

Comment: @Vivick My dice are all stateful. Unless there's an earthquake they keep the face up I last threw them.

Answer (score 2):

Your design is basically correct. The only thing is the missing `-` in front of the `faceValue` attribute. I'm not sure if a missing indicator default to something (could not find and indication at a first glance). Anyhow, you should add it to make it explicit.

Also, `Dice` should be renamed to `Die` (singular).

Finally (looking more deeply into you code) you need an array of `Die` with 2 elements rather than just one `dice` and you need to roll both dice.

Comment: Just curious here, since there is 2 marked to indicate number of dices shouldn't we somehow incorporate them as well?

Comment: @NicholasK They are just fine. When implementing this you'd likely do that with an array having 2 elements. However, implementing `die1` and `die2` instead would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think the dice is not a part of the gambler,The gambler only has the act of rolling the dice.I think the implementation below would be better:

```
class Gambler{
    //some field

    public int roll(Dice dice){
        return dice.roll();
    }
}

/* --------------------------- */

import java.util.Random;
class Dice{
     private int[] values = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};

     public int roll(){
         //get random value between 1 ,6
         Random random = new Random();
         return values[random.nextInt((6 - 1) + 1) + 1];
     }
}
```

Of course,it depends on actual requirement.

Comment: between Gambler and dice classes have association relationship .
association means Link . that is why in Gambler class there is a class variable for dice object.

Comment: as per your implementation there is no association but there is dependency among Gambler and Dice

Comment: `Gambler` needs an association (owned property) to `Dice` (which should correctly be named singular as `Die`) since how else can he roll them?